# Using a theorem on integer numbers for proving a theorem on natural numbers

Tags: coq

I'm not a mathematician, but I take interest in the topic and the use of proof assistants like Coq. I still need to learn *a lot* on how Coq works. As an exercise, I would like to proof that:

```
forall n : nat, n > 0 -> Nat.Odd n <-> Nat.Odd (5 * n + 6).
```

I failed to proof this directly and therefore thought of taking a roundtrip via the integers:

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Lia.

Theorem T1 : forall n : Z,
  Z.Odd n <-> Z.Odd (5 * n + 6).
Proof.
  unfold Z.Odd.
  intros. split.
  - intros. destruct H as [x G]. rewrite G. exists ((5 * x + 5)%Z). lia.
  - intros. destruct H as [x G]. exists ((-2 * n - 3 + x)%Z). lia.
Qed.
```

I would now like to use this result to proof the initial theorem. Unfortunately, I get stuck in relating `Nat.Odd` to `Z.Odd` and the eventual application of `T1`:

```
Lemma L1 : forall n : nat,
  Z.Odd (Z.of_nat n) <-> Nat.Odd n.
Proof.
  intros.
  Admitted.

Theorem T2 : forall n : nat,
  n > 0 -> Nat.Odd n <-> Nat.Odd (5 * n + 6).
Proof.
  intros.
  pose proof T1 as G.
  rewrite <- L1.
  rewrite <- L1.
  Admitted.
```

I would like to know if I'm on the right track here. I'm also seeking for some hints on how to eventually proof `T2` using the result `T1` (assuming that this is actually a sensible approach to proving the initial goal using Coq).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a way to prove this goal staying in Nat (by using a divisibility argument) but this approach is also feasible.
The lemma `L1` on which you got stuck can actually be solved in a similar fashion as the theorem `T1`, leveraging `lia` for finding the right lemmas. Then, the only thing in your way to apply `T1` in the course of proving `T2` is to show that `Z.of_nat` respects addition and multiplication: you can rely another time on `lia`. All together you obtain the following proof:

```
From Coq Require Import ZArith Arith.PeanoNat Psatz.

Theorem T1 : forall n : Z, Z.Odd n <-> Z.Odd (5 * n + 6).
Admitted.

Lemma L1 (n : nat) : Z.Odd (Z.of_nat n) <-> Nat.Odd n.
Proof.
  split.
  - intros [x?]. exists (Z.to_nat x). lia.
  - intros [x?]. exists (Z.of_nat x). lia.
Qed.

Theorem T2 (n : nat) : Nat.Odd n <-> Nat.Odd (5 * n + 6).
Proof.
  do 2 rewrite <- L1.
  (* We need to massage slightly the goal to apply T1 *)
  assert (Z.of_nat (5*n + 6) = (5*(Z.of_nat n)+6)%Z) as -> by lia.
  apply T1.
Qed.
```